# 'no matching index found' when using ORDER BY

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I've gone through all the questions and created a multitude of indexes that all work independently, but the second I try to add an ORDER BY I get an 'no matching index found.' error

These are the indexes I'm using

```
indexes:
- kind: gallery-public
  properties:
  - name: public
  - name: flavor
  - name: created
    direction : desc
- kind: get-selfies
  properties:
  - name: flavor
  - name: public
  - name: created
    direction: desc
- kind: get-selfies
  properties:
  - name: flavor
  - name: created
    direction: asc
- kind: get-all
  properties:
  - name: public
  - name: created
    direction: desc
- kind: get-all-old
  properties:
  - name: public
  - name: created
    direction: asc
- kind: get-all-two
  properties:
  - name: flavor
  - name: created
    direction: desc
```

Every query works

```
SELECT * FROM upload WHERE flavor="whatever" AND public=true
```

**Until** I add an ORDER BY, in which case nothing works. Such as:

```
SELECT * FROM upload WHERE public=true ORDER BY created DESC
```

I've created all of those indexes, explicitly defined the description, left the order field to the end, and I still can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an index for the kind `upload`:

```
- kind: upload
  properties:
  - name: public
  - name: created
    direction: desc
```

FYI The query without the `ORDER BY` succeeds because it can use the [built-in single property index](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) on property `public`.  By adding the `ORDER BY`, you need to have a composite index on both the `public` and `created` properties.

Comment: Yes this was the issue. Resolved it this morning. The docs are unclear that the kind in the index can be used in the query so if I index as get-all I can "GET * FROM get-all" -- I had been assuming that it would always have to be the entity kind.

Answer (score 0):

There are more properties being returned by that query than `public`, `created`, and `flavor`.

Instead:

```
SELECT public,created,flavor FROM upload WHERE public=true ORDER BY created DESC
```

Give us a sample record from `SELECT *` if that's not the case.

Any property(field) that is returned by a query must also be part of your custom index.